# Динамическое увеличение количества объектов ttk.Entry

Tags: python, tkinter

Делаю простенький интерфейс для работы с sql. При выборе нужной таблицы, пользователю отображается интерфейс добавления новых записей, поэтому надо динамически изменять количество объектов label и entry.

Я создал список объектов StringVar и IntVar. В дальнейшем присваиваю каждому Entry свой указатель на объект из списка.Проблема в том, что переменные не запоминают значения.

```py
for i, row in enumerate(rows):
    new_data.append(StringVar() if not row[1] == 'NUMBER' else IntVar())
    for j, name in enumerate(row):
        ttk.Label(f3, text=name, width=15).grid(row=i + 1, column=j)
    ttk.Entry(f3, textvariable=new_data[i], width=15).grid(row=i + 1, column=j + 1)
```

Как это реализовать правильно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Отказался от переменных, т.к. у Entry тоже есть метод get.

```py
data = []
for i, row in enumerate(rows):
    for j, name in enumerate(row):
        ttk.Label(f3, text=name, width=15).grid(row=i + 1, column=j)
    data.append(ttk.Entry(f3, width=15))
    data[-1].grid(row=i + 1, column=j + 1)
```